# How to exclude changesets in build trigger?

Tags: bamboo

I have a build plan in Bamboo (5.10.0, build 51017), and in the end of my build process, I push changes to my Git repository (Bitbucket Server), with a  message with the following format:  `<build key>: Commit performed by the build server.`.

My build plan key is `AAB-AC`, and the commit message always starts with the key of the build, such as `AAB-AC7-JOB1-75` (`${bamboo.buildResultKey}`).

I have tried many different regular expressions in the *Exclude changesets* field of the *Advanced options* of my repository, but a new build is always triggered whenever a build completes.

Here are a few examples of the patterns I have tried:

- `^AAB-\S*-\S*-\d*:`
- `^AAB-AC\S*-\S*-\d*:.*$`
- `^AAB-AC`
- `AAB-AC`
- `^AAB-AC\S*-\S*-\d*:.*\n`
- `^AAB-AC.*$`
- `^AAB-AC.*-.*-.*:`
- `Commit performed by the build server`

For each of these regular expressions, whenever I run a build manually, a new build is started right after my build finishes and the Bamboo server enters an infinite loop and endlessly builds my app.

How can I make Bamboo ignore the commits performed by my build plan?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to make this work...

- I have branches on my plan and I found that branch plans have their own repository definition with their own *Exclude changesets* setting.

  - So I tried all the regex combinations for nothing since the value specified on the branch plan was used, and not the value I defined on the main plan...
- It seems that the `^` character is used to negate the regex, instead of matching the beginning of the string...

  - So the pattern `^AAB-AC` seems to match everything that *does not contain `AAB-AC`*

    - All the commits I pushed to my server that didn't contain AAB-AC were ignored
    - All the commits pushed by my build plan triggered a new build

So I fixed my regex and I updated all my branch plans and everything seems to work properly.

Thank you for your help,

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Most of those should work, we use `^Tag:.*$` in "Exclude changesets" to exclude commits like "Tag: v1.0.0" from triggering a build.

This worked in Bamboo 4, but doesn't work since we upgraded to 5.10.2 build 51019. So my guess is that this is a bug in Bamboo

Comment: Ya I am noticing the same thing as you. I am having no luck getting this to exclude my changesets. I have verified the regex a few times and seems valid.